# How to concatenate two object with array properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have two objects:

```
var one = {
  addedItems: [0, 1],
  removedItems: [8, 9],
  oneTwo: false,
  someStuff: {
    anotherArray: ['a', 'b']
  }
};

var two = {
  addedItems: [3, 4],
  removedItems: [6, 7],
  someStuff: {
    anotherArray: ['c', 'd']
  }
};
```

And in the end I need to merge these two objects and get something like this:

```
{
  addedItems: [0, 1, 3, 4],
  removedItems: [8, 9, 6, 7],
  oneTwo: false,
  someStuff: {
    anotherArray: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  }
}
```

The operation should be performed on objects with different structure.

What is the best way (or just possible way) to do this? Are there any methods in jQuery or underscore/lodash that allow to do this?

Comment: To clarify... if both objects have a property that is an array, you want to merge the 2 into each other... however what happens if `a.foo:true` and `b.foo:false` which one takes precedence when the values are atomic? Likewise if the values in the array contain duplicates do you want duplicates or just unique values?

Comment: The last one. For example if we have doConcatenation(one, two), the property from "two" will be the result property.

Comment: The concept is known as deep merging, and there is an excellent `deepmerge` library. [Here is a blog (published yesterday) about it.](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-deep-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a new object and append arrays with the items from the already inserted array.

```js
function deepMerge(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        if (Array.isArray(source[k])) {
            if (!Array.isArray(target[k])) {
                target[k] = [];
            }          
            target[k] = target[k].concat(source[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (source[k] && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            target[k] = target[k] || {};
            deepMerge(source[k], target[k]);
            return;
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
}

var one = { addedItems: [0, 1], removedItems: [8, 9], oneTwo: false, someStuff: { anotherArray: ['a', 'b'] } },
    two = { addedItems: [3, 4], removedItems: [6, 7], someStuff: { anotherArray: ['c', 'd'] } },
    result = {};

deepMerge(one, result);
deepMerge(two, result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you check Lodash `_.mergeWith(object, sources, customizer)` method? I think the example does what you are basically expecting.

[https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith)

```
var one = { addedItems: [0, 1], removedItems: [8, 9], oneTwo: false, someStuff: { anotherArray: ['a', 'b'] } },
    two = { addedItems: [3, 4], removedItems: [6, 7], someStuff: { anotherArray: ['c', 'd'] } };

// In case of arrays, concatenate them instead
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}

var result = _.mergeWith(one, two, customizer);
```

[Here's the working example in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4j4sdbz)